# Three questions on $\operatorname{hocolim}$

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

I posted this on [math.stack.exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) but didn't get a helpful response, so please let me try it here.

Let $D$ be a small category and $F:D\to sSets$ a functor.

There is a bisimplicial set indicated by 
$$
...\begin{array}{c}\to \\ \to\\\to\end{array}\coprod_{d_1\to d_0}F(d_1)\begin{array}{c}\to\\\to\end{array}\coprod_{d_0}F(d_0)
$$
which i like to call $sres(F)_{\bullet\bullet}$. By considering either the horizontal or the vertical index first, I get two functors $H:\Delta^{op}\to sSets$ and $V:\Delta^{op}\to sSets$ (the ''vertical'' direction is the one of the simplicial sets $F(d)$, i.e. each object in the diagram above should be imagined as a vertical column).

The [homotopy colimit](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+limit#homotopy_colimits_over_diagrams_of_spaces_91) $\operatorname{hocolim}F$ of $F$ can be defined in different ways (up to weak equivalence) and one way is $(\operatorname{hocolim}F)_n=sres(F)_{n n}$, the diagonal of $sres(F)_{\bullet\bullet}$.

> Is there a weak equivalence between between $\operatorname{hocolim}F$ and $\operatorname{hocolim}H$? (I don't think there is a weak equivalence between $\operatorname{hocolim}F$ and $\operatorname{hocolim}V$, or is it?)

Let me call a simplicial set $A$ *$k$-dimensional*, if it is equal to its $k$-[skeleton](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+skeleton) $\mathbf{sk}_k$ (If I am not mistaken, $k$ should be the smallest integer such that all elements of $A_{k+1}$ are degenerated simplices).

> Suppose that the [nerve](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nerve) $N(D)$ of $D$ is weakly equivalent to a simplicial set $A$ of dimension $k$. Is it true that $\operatorname{hocolim}F$ is weak equivalent to the homotopy colimit of the diagram
>   $$
> \coprod_{d_{k+1}\to ...\to d_0}F(d_{k+1})\begin{array}{c}\to \\ \vdots\\\to\end{array}...\begin{array}{c}\to \\ \to\\\to\end{array}\coprod_{d_1\to d_0}F(d_1)\begin{array}{c}\to\\\to\end{array}\coprod_{d_0}F(d_0),
> $$
>   (the truncated $H$) or in other words, can I ''stop'' at the $k+1$th stage of the diagram in the horizontal direction to calculate the homotopy colimit? If yes, why?

In particular, if $D$ is linear (for example $\mathbb{N}$ or $\cdot\to\cdot\to\cdot$), this would mean, that $\operatorname{hocolim}F$ is the homotopy colimit of the simple diagram
$$
\coprod_{d_1\to d_0}F(d_1)\begin{array}{c}\to\\\to\end{array}\coprod_{d_0}F(d_0).
$$

---

My third question is a little vague and like the second one but not ''for the source'' of $F$ but ''for the target''. Please don't hesitate to post an answer only to the first two questions, if this third one is not well formulated. I wondered, why one takes only two-limits of stacks and not $k$-limits. The nerve of a category is a [2-coskeletal](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+skeleton#examples_20) simplicial set and this is where the reason comes from, I guess.

> Suppose the functor $F$ factorize through the nerve $F:D\to CAT\xrightarrow{N} sSets$. Is it true that $\operatorname{hocolim}F$ is weakly equivalent to the homotopy colimit of the diagram
>   $$
> \coprod_{d_2\to d_1\to d_0}F(d_{2})\begin{array}{c}\to \\ \to\\\to\end{array}\coprod_{d_1\to d_0}F(d_1)\begin{array}{c}\to\\\to\end{array}\coprod_{d_0}F(d_0)
> $$
>   and what is the reason? If not, what did I misunderstand here?

Comment: Now that MSE and MO are on the same networks you can flag for a moderator attention on MSE and request the question to be migrated here.

Comment: 2-limits have to do with 2-category theory and are related to homotopy limits in certain cases, but they are not the same thing. For instance, 2-limits can be defined uniquely up to isomorphism.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**First question**$\newcommand{\op}[1]{{#1}^{\mathrm{op}}}$$\newcommand{\sSet}{\mathrm{sSet}}$$\newcommand{\Grpd}{\mathrm{Grpd}}$$\newcommand{\Cat}{\mathrm{Cat}}$$\newcommand{\NN}{\mathbb{N}}$$\newcommand{\sres}{\mathrm{sres}}$$\newcommand{\hocolim}{\operatorname{hocolim}}$$\newcommand{\diag}{\operatorname{diag}}$$\newcommand{\To}{\longrightarrow}$$\newcommand{\real}[1]{\lvert #1 \rvert}$

The homotopy colimit of a functor $X:\op{\Delta}\to\sSet$ is equivalent to its geometric realization $\real{X}$. This holds because every functor $\op{\Delta}\to\sSet$ is cofibrant in the Reedy model structure. In particular, geometric realization of simplicial simplicial sets preserves objectwise weak equivalences. You may consult corollary 15.8.8 and theorem 18.7.4 in Hirschhorn's book "*Model categories and their localizations*" for these results. The equivalence between the homotopy colimit and the geometric realization is given explicitly by the [Bousfield–Kan map](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Bousfield-Kan+map) (in section 18.7 of Hirschhorn's book).

On the other hand, it is a very interesting well-known fact that the geometric realization of a simplicial simplicial set $X:\op{\Delta}\to\sSet$ is canonically isomorphic to the diagonal $\diag X$ of the associated bisimplicial set. You will find this as theorem 15.11.6 of Hirschhorn's book, or as exercise IV.1.4 in the book "Simplicial homotopy theory*" by Goerss and Jardine. [Further, if you are very categorically inclined, you may see this quite formally as a consequence of geometric realization being a coend whose weight is the Yoneda embedding.]

From the preceding paragraphs, we conclude that there is a natural weak equivalence $\hocolim X\overset{\sim}{\To}\diag X$ for every simplicial simplicial set $X$. This is stated explicitly as corollary 18.7.7 of Hirschhorn's book.

What I said so far is in part briefly described in section XII.3.4 of the book "Homotopy limits, completions and localizations" by Bousfield and Kan.

> **Answer to first question:** We conclude from the previous discussion that the homotopy colimits of both $H$ and $V$ are naturally equivalent to their diagonals. Each of these diagonals is by definition also the diagonal of $\sres(F)$, i.e. your proposed definition for the homotopy colimit of $F$.

[As a consistency check, the definition of homotopy colimit of a diagram $F:D\to\sSet$ given in both Bousfield–Kan and Hirschhorn is isomorphic to your definition as the diagonal of $\sres(F)$. You can see a brief explanation of this fact in section 4.13 of Dan Dugger's notes "[*A primer on homotopy colimits*](http://pages.uoregon.edu/ddugger/hocolim.pdf)". These are very readable notes, and I highly recommend them. You can also read about the Bousfield–Kan map in section 17.2 of those notes.]

**Second question**

> The answer to your second question is *no*.

Take the very simple category $D$ described schematically as $0\overset{a}{\to} 1\overset{b}{\to} 2$. Then the category $D$ has a terminal object so its nerve is contractible, and we may take $k=0$ in your second question. Consider the terminal functor $F=\ast : D\to \sSet$ whose value is always the terminal simplicial set with a single vertex, and no non-degenerate higher dimensional simplices. The homotopy colimit of this diagram is equivalent to the nerve of $D$, and thus contractible. On the other hand, the $1$-truncated simplicial object you write in your question is levelwise discrete, so we can think of it as a simplicial set with:

- three vertices $0$, $1$, and $2$
- three non-degenerate edges: $a$ from $0$ to $1$, $b$ from $1$ to $2$, and $ab$ from $0$ to $2$.

Non-coincidentally, this is just the $1$-skeleton of the nerve of $D$. It is quite easy to see that its realization is a circle. Thus the homotopy colimit of your $1$-truncated simplicial object is not contractible. The problem is of course that we "erased" the non-degenerate $2$-simplex from the nerve of $D$, thus changing its homotopy type.

> On a positive note, I believe a formula *like* the one you state does hold. Under the stronger assumption that the nerve of $D$ is $k$-skeletal, then the homotopy colimit of $F:D\to\sSet$ is equivalent to the homotopy colimit of a $k$-truncated simplicial object like the one you write (except you write a $(k+1)$-truncated simplicial object instead). [By a $k$-truncated simplicial object, I mean a functor indexed by the full subcategory of $\op{\Delta}$ spanned by the $n$-simplices with $n\leq k$.]

*Sketch of proof*: If the nerve of $D$ is $k$-skeletal, $\sres(F)$ is also (horizontally) $k$-skeletal. Consequently, the diagonal of $\sres(F)$ coincides with the geometric realization of the horizontal $k$-truncation of $\sres(F)$ (in your question you actually write down the $(k+1)$-truncation). This is equivalent to the homotopy colimit of the $k$-truncation for the same reasons as before: every $k$-truncated simplicial object in simplicial sets is Reedy cofibrant (which actually follows from the analogous result for simplicial simplicial sets).

**Intermezzo**

I will make a couple of simple comments regarding your examples in between the second and third questions.

The homotopy colimit of any functor $F$ indexed by a category $D$ with a terminal object $d$ is weakly equivalent to $F(d)$. So the homotopy colimit of any functor $F$ indexed by $0\to 1\to 2$ is weakly equivalent to $F(2)$.

Moreover, any filtered colimit in simplicial sets is actually a homotopy colimit, essentially because filtered colimits commute with homotopy groups in $\sSet$. In other words, homotopy colimits in $\sSet$ along filtered categories (such as $\NN$) are no harder than ordinary colimits.

**Third question**

For this question, the relevant part about stacks is not that they have values in categories. It is that they have values in *groupoids*. Moreover, one needs to take the homotopy colimit *in groupoids* and not in simplicial sets. I will elaborate below.

First, here is a counter-example to your third question as it stands. Consider any category $C$ whose nerve is equivalent to $S^3$, for example. [Any simplicial set is weakly equivalent to the nerve of some category, for example its category of simplices. Here, however, is an explicit example for $S^3$: simply take the [join of categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/join+of+categories) $C = 2\ast 2 \ast 2 \ast 2$, where $2$ denotes a discrete category with two objects.] Then the homotopy colimit along $C$ of the nerve of the constant terminal functor $\ast:C\to\Cat$ is simply
$$ \hocolim N(\ast) = \hocolim \ast \simeq BC \simeq S^3 $$
However, the homotopy colimit of the corresponding $2$-truncated simplicial set you write will be equivalent to its geometric realization, which is $2$-dimensional. In particular, it cannot have non-trivial homology in dimension $3$, and cannot be equivalent to $S^3$.

What is true is that the homotopy colimit *in groupoids* (with respect to the [natural model structure](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/canonical+model+structure+on+groupoids)) of a functor $F:D\to\Grpd$ (from $D$ to the category of groupoids) is equivalent to the homotopy colimit *in groupoids* of the $2$-truncated simplicial object you write down.

If you want to further compose $F:D\to\Grpd$ with the nerve functor, then you will have to apply the fundamental groupoid functor to the homotopy colimit of $N\circ F$ in simplicial sets to recover the homotopy colimit of $F$ in groupoids. This holds because the fundamental groupoid functor is part of a Quillen adjunction between simplicial sets and groupoids. The same holds for the homotopy colimit of the $2$-truncated simplicial object you write down.

Comment: Dear @Ricardo Andrade, thank you for the very helpful answer! In the proof of the ''positive note'', what means $k$-skeletal for a bisimplicial set like $sref(F)$? Does it mean ''horizontally $k$-skeletal''?

Comment: Good catch! I was looking at the way you wrote $sres(F)$, which looks like a simplicial object in simplicial sets. I meant $k$-skeletal in the first direction, which I guess is horizontally. I will edit the answer. Finally, you are welcome. I am glad to help!

Comment: Dear @Ricardo Andrade, concerning the ''lemma'' in the second answer and third answer: Is the nerve of a groupoid $3$-skeletal?

Comment: @Ronald: The nerve of any category with non-identity isomorphisms has non-degenerate simplices in every dimension. For example, the nerve of a groupoid with two objects and an isomorphism between them is infinite dimensional, and thus not $k$-skeletal for any $k$. When I have the time, I may try to add some details explaining why homotopy colimits in groupoids can be computed by a 2-truncated simplicial object (but I am afraid it may take me a while). Finally, what do you mean by the lemma in the second answer?

Comment: Dear @Ricardo, ''lemma'' should refer to your proved statement that if $D$ is $k$-skeletal, the homotopy colimit of $F$ is equivalent to the homotopy colimit of the horizontally $k$-truncated object. I thought that this would help to see why homotopy colimits in groupoids can be computed by a $2$-truncated object but as you explained, the reason has to be another one. Thank you!

Comment: @Ronald: The reason is indeed different. Briefly, it happens because the inclusion into $\Delta$ of its full subcategory spanned by the $k$-simplices for $k\leq 2$ is "homotopy 1-final", in the sense that the relevant over-categories have simply connected nerve (homotopy final would mean instead that the over-categories have contractible nerve). I am afraid I will not be able to add details concerning this stuff to my answer over the next few days, but I will do so when I have some time.

Comment: Dear Ricardo, what is the reason that for index category $D=\mathbb{N}$ one may restrict to the $1$ truncated $\coprod$-thing? The nerve of $\mathbb{N}$ is not $1$-truncated so your third gray box doesn't apply. Thank you.

Comment: Dear @jeffrey, in the case of the category $\newcommand{\NN}{\mathbb{N}} \NN$, we cannot compute the homotopy colimit of a functor $F:\NN\to\mathrm{sSet}$ using the 1-truncation of the bar construction $B(F,\NN,\ast)$ (this bar construction is precisely the "$\coprod$-thing"). In fact, the realization of that 1-truncation for $F=\ast$ is the 1-skeleton of the classifying space of $\NN$, which consists of the set $\NN$ with one segment added between each pair of distinct points of $\NN$. This space is not contractible, thus cannot be the homotopy colimit of $F=\ast$. (to be continued...)

Comment: (continuation) The preceding counter-example is very similar to the one in the second part of my answer above. However, there is a sub-object of the 1-truncation of the bar construction which will compute the homotopy colimit of $F$: at level one, consider only the morphisms $n \to n+1$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and remove all other morphisms from the 1-truncated bar construction. The realization of this sub-object is precisely the mapping telescope of the functor $F$, and is therefore equivalent to the homotopy colimit of $F$.